# How to migrate browser-based HTML5 and Javascript code into Xcode?

Tags: javascript, html, xcode

I have an HTML file containing JavaScript code, which is read by PC browsers(like IE).
Now I want to "migrate" those codes to make it part of my iOS app.

Is there an easy way to do this? I now using Titanium is a good way but what if I intend to use Xcode? (Also, the HTML contains some JQuery codes.)

Thank you very much!

Comment: XCode is an IDE. Titanium is a wrapper around a browser control. You can't sanely compare them.

Answer (score 4):

Use [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and you can run it as is.